# Why does the kernel quit if I want to use minus a sum that I converted from a list?

Tags: bugs, expression-manipulation

Using Mathematica 11 when I define a list

```
yy = {x*43, 32*y};
```

and then convert it to a sum

```
yy[[0]] = Plus;
yy
```

I get, as expected, x*43 + 32*y.

However, as soon as I try to multiply my sum with a minus sign, i.e. when I execute

```
-yy
```

my kernel quits without any error message.

Any ideas why this happens and how to avoid it?

---

The problem can be avoided by converting the list using a Do loop:

```
sum = 0;
Do[
  sum = sum + yy[[i]],
  {i, Length[yy]}
  ];
sum
-sum
(* 43 x + 32 y *)
(* -43 x - 32 y *)
```

Comment: I can reproduce it on Win10 V10.4 - V11.3

Comment: Same on win7 64 bit.

Comment: p.s. `Tr` or `Total` or `Plus @@` are more idiomatic than `Do`. And all work.

Comment: Reproduced for V11.0.1 and V11.3 on macOS. Voting for bug tag.

Comment: Please report it to WRI support.

Comment: Surely one of the weirdest bugs I've seen. `-2 yy` works just fine. `-2 yy/2` crashes the kernel again, and so does `I I yy`.

Comment: Mathematica 8.0.4 on Win7x64 is not affected, this bug is not reproduced there. Does someone have Mathematica 9 at hand to check?

Comment: Reproduced on MMA 11 and Windows 8.1. So Mathematica 11 has kernel crashes from 3 lines of code, using core functionality introduced in version 1.0? So much for 'everything is industrial strength'.

Comment: Error still occurs in Mathematica 12, running on Ubuntu 20.04.